# Вывод значения метода в Textbox и в listbox одновременно, как реализовать?

Tags: c#

Доброй ночи, нужна помощь с выводом информации.
Есть вот такой код

```
public static void GetPhotosListInAlbum(ListBox PhotoList)
{
    var getPhotos = vk.Photo.Get(new PhotoGetParams
    {
        OwnerId = ShareData.SelectedUid,
        AlbumId = PhotoAlbumType.Id(ShareData.AlbumID),
        Reversed = false,
        //  PhotoSizes = true, 
    });

    foreach (var photo in getPhotos)
    {
        PhotoList.Items.Add(photo.Id);
    }
    foreach (var link in getPhotos)
    {
        ShareData.PhotoLink = link.Photo604.ToString();
    }
}
```

Мне собственно надо следующее, что бы по клику элемента в `listbox` в самом `listbox` была информация о `photo.Id` а в `textbox` ссылка на это фото.
Я добавил второй цикл `foreach` но в `textbox` выводит только ссылку на первый элемент. Как сделать правильно?

Я могу вывести ссылку в `ListBox` просто дописав к `photo.id` еще photo.url

```
foreach (var photo in getPhotos)
    {
        PhotoList.Items.Add(photo.Id + " " + photo.url);
    }
```

Но тогда он мне выведет и `id` и ссылку в `ListBox`.
Я же хочу ссылку `url` получить в `textbox` на форме. А `id` пусть останется в `ListBox`.

[image: То что сейчас у меня]

Вот ссылку напротив надо убрать из `ListBox` и вывести ее в `TextBox`.
Выбрав `id` фото надо получить актуальную ссылку на фото в `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что бы по клику элемента в `listbox` в самом `listbox` была информация о
>   `photo.Id` а в `textbox` ссылка на это фото.

Начнём с того, что, если судить по представленному Вами коду, у Вас в `ListBox` уже изначально отображаются `id` фото. Поэтому, можно в соответствующем событии (`SelectedIndexChanged` (WinForms) или `SelectionChanged` (WPF)) при выборе элемента в `ListBox` по `id` отобразить ссылку.

```
string id = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
textBox1.Text = photos.getPhotoLinkById(id);
```

Приблизительно как-то так...

Comment: Хм, любопытное "выдирание" элемента из `ListBox`, а почему просто `listBox1.SelectedItem` не использовать, или есть какие то "подводные камни"?

Comment: Все верно, сейчас у меня там только id фотографии показывает.
Может просто я заковыристо описываю свою проблему.
В foreach можно еще вывести помимо id фотографии еще и ссылку на нее. И через Items.Add внести в ListBox.
Ваш вариант, выводит мне id фото в TextBox.
 foreach (var photo in getPhotos)
    {
        PhotoList.Items.Add(photo.Id);
    }
Вот в этом цикле есть еще свойство у photo под названием url. Вот его то мне и надо в текстбокс формы.